# Partial fractions of $1/(z^2+2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-fractions

How does one split $1/(z^2+2)$ into partial fractions?

Normally I would factorise, but I cannot spot the solutions of $z^2+2=0$.

Comment: Normally i would factorise, but i cannot spot the solution

Comment: $z^2+2=0$ implies $z^2=-2$, write down $-1=i^2$ and you have $z^2=2i^2$. What $z$ satisfy this?

Comment: I have i times plus minus root 2. These must be the roots, it seems so simple now, thank you.

Comment: In general, $(x^2 + y^2)$, with $x$ and $y$ real, factors into $(x + iy)(x - iy)$.

Comment: Also, if $k_1,k_2,...k_n$ are roots of a monic polynomial of degree $n$, then that polynomial can be written as $(z-k_1)(z-k_2)...(z-k_n)$. It's a good thing that in $\mathbb C$ all non linear polynomials are reducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor $z^2 + 2 = (z + \sqrt{2}i)(z - \sqrt{2}i)$. Note $(z + \sqrt{2}i) - (z - \sqrt{2}i) = 2\sqrt{2}i$. So we have

$$\frac{1}{z^2 + 2} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}i} \frac{(z + \sqrt{2}i) - (z - \sqrt{2}i)}{(z + \sqrt{2}i)(z - \sqrt{2}i)} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}i}\left(\frac{1}{z - \sqrt{2}i} - \frac{1}{z + \sqrt{2}i}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Tip:

$z^2+2=0$ at $z_0=\sqrt{2}i$ and $z_1=-\sqrt{2}i$

So $z^2+2=(z-\sqrt{2}i)(z+\sqrt{2}i)$. (Check this)

Write down $\frac{1}{z^2+2}=\frac{1}{(z-\sqrt{2}i)(z+\sqrt{2}i)}$

Now, can you find $A,B \in \mathbb C$ such that $\frac{1}{(z-\sqrt{2}i)(z+\sqrt{2}i)}=\frac{A}{z+\sqrt{2}i}+\frac{B}{z-\sqrt{2}i}$?

Comment: Wouldn't A=B=1?

Comment: the numerator would be $2z$ so no. try again.

Comment: @MathsPro : No, because then the numerator would be $2z$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ive multiplied up to get

$$ 2z+2=A(z-\sqrt{2} i)+B(z + \sqrt{2} i)$$

Comment: the script for square rooti is \sqrt{} where you put the number in the {}.

Comment: $B=1+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}i}$ i think.

Comment: My Solution;

$A=1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}i}$
$B=1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}i}$

Answer (score 1):

Start with $z^2+2=(z-i\sqrt{2})(z+i\sqrt{2})$ So we are looking for $$\frac{1}{z^2+1}=\frac{a}{z-i\sqrt{2}}+\frac{b}{z+i\sqrt{2}}$$ Because the LHS is real $a$ and $b$ are complex conjugate. Multiplying by $z-i\sqrt{2}$ we get $$\frac{1}{z+i\sqrt{2}}=a+\bar{a}\frac{z-i\sqrt{2}}{z+i\sqrt{2}}$$ and this is valid for all $z$ especially for $z=i\sqrt{2}$ which cancels the second term of the RHS and yields $a=\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{2}}$